# I am using php routing for the first time and I have been getting error Sorry! Page not found

Tags: php

```
These are the files that I have been working on
//routes.php 
     <?php
    $routes = array(
        '/'=>'controller/mainpagecontroller.php',
    );
    
    
    function router($routes)
    {
        foreach ($routes as $path => $content) {
            if ($path == $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) {
                // If the path matches, redirect to its content page.
                return header("location:$content");
            }
        }
        echo 'Sorry! Page not found';
    }
    
    router($routes);
    ?>
    
    //controller/mainpagecontroller.php
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style and responsive\style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/addpost"><button class="one" >Create post</button></a>
    </body>
    </html>
  
    
    //index.php
    <?php
    require 'db/bootstrap.php';
    ?>
```

But when i type localhost/Project/index.php/ it gets redirected to http://localhost/Project/index.php/controller/mainpagecontroller.php page
and shows sorry page not found.

Comment: If you use `header` - you then need to use something like `exit` to stop the code continuing on.

Comment: You're doing a redirect. That's not that way you're supposed to do routing. You shouldn't be linking to index.php like that either. You should be using something like .htaccess (assuming Apache) for pointing to the index.php file. Then define your routes where you can tie different routes to various controllers, etc. See the laravel way of routing here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing

Comment: Are you sure you're using laravel?

Comment: No, I am using php

Comment: Any suggestions why it is showing sorry page not found?

Comment: This question is not belongs to [tag:laravel], please [edit] and delete unrelated tags

Comment: Try dumping the value of `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`

Comment: Done didn't help.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't help"? My suggestion was to look at, and tell us, the content of that variable - your code assumes it is going to be equal to `'/'`, but is it?

Answer (score 0):

Using `$_SERVER["PATH_INFO"]` won't help sometimes because its only present when a PHP script is invoked in this way:

```
http://something.com/index.php/some_page
```

It is recommended to determine the path in this way:

```php
function getRequestPath() {
   $path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   $pos = strpos($path, "?");

   return substr($path, 0, $pos === false ? strlen($path) : $pos);
}
```

Calling this function will give you the base path (without the query string) and you can then find the appropriate route using this path.

Comment: Done now it shows blank page

Comment: Any more suggestions please?

Comment: Did you replaced `if ($path == $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) {` with `if ($path === getRequestPath()) {` in your `routes()` function?